# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' error when trying to fit a 2d array

Tags: python, list, nlp, attributeerror

Im trying to train a model to detect fake news and am trying to make a bag of words model. However when I try to fit my model i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/fake news 2.py", line 89, in <module>
    headline_bow.fit(lower)
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1186, in fit
    self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1220, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1131, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 103, in _analyze
    doc = preprocessor(doc)
  File "/Users/amanpuranik/PycharmProjects/covid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 68, in _preprocess
    doc = doc.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Im not sure why im getting this error. This is the dataset im trying to fit:

```
[['four', 'way', 'bob', 'corker', 'skewer', 'donald', 'trump'], ['linklat', "'s", 'war', 'veteran', 'comedi', 'speak', 'modern', 'america', ',', 'say', 'star'], ['trump', '’', 'fight', 'with', 'corker', 'jeopard', 'his', 'legisl', 'agenda']]
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/amanpuranik/Desktop/fake-news-detection/data.csv")
data = data[['Headline', "Label"]]

x = np.array(data['Headline'])
print(x[0])
y = np.array(data["Label"])

# tokenization of the data here'
headline_vector = []

for  headline in x:
    headline_vector.append(word_tokenize(headline))

print(headline_vector)



stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

#removing stopwords at this part
filtered = [[word for word in sentence if word not in stopwords]
            for sentence in headline_vector]
#print(filtered)


stemmed2 = [[stem(word) for word in headline] for headline in filtered]
#print(stemmed2)

#lowercase
lower = [[word.lower() for word in headline] for headline in stemmed2] #start here

#organising
articles = []


for headline in lower:
    articles.append(headline)

#creating the bag of words model

headline_bow = CountVectorizer()
headline_bow.fit(lower)
a = headline_bow.transform(lower)
```

why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: ... NameError for lower ... where do you declare it?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code fails to run.

Comment: Sorry about that I accidentally left out  a chunk of code. I updated it.

Comment: `lower` is 2-dimensional list - you have list with lists of words. Maybe `fit()` expects 1-dimensional list - list of words. So you may have to convert list of lists to flat list, or you have to run `fit()` in `for`-loop with every list of words separatelly.

Comment: documentation for [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) shows it has to be list of strings, not list of lists of strings. So you may have to convert every list of words into single string to have list of sentences instead of list of list of words.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess.

Documentation for [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) shows it has to be list of strings (1-dimensional list) but you have list of lists of word (2-dimensional list)

You may have to convert evey list of words to string (sentence)

```
lower_sentences = [" ".join(x) for x in lower]
```

and then you can use it

```
headline_bow = CountVectorizer()
headline_bow.fit(lower_sentences)
a = headline_bow.transform(lower_sentences)
```

---

Working example

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

lower = [['four', 'way', 'bob', 'corker', 'skewer', 'donald', 'trump'], ['linklat', "'s", 'war', 'veteran', 'comedi', 'speak', 'modern', 'america', ',', 'say', 'star'], ['trump', '’', 'fight', 'with', 'corker', 'jeopard', 'his', 'legisl', 'agenda']]

lower_sentences = [' '.join(words) for words in lower]

headline_bow = CountVectorizer()
headline_bow.fit(lower_sentences)
a = headline_bow.transform(lower_sentences)
```